# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.slim' has no attribute 'nets'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-slim

I want to use the built in `resnet` in `tf-slim` for a quick experiment. I did according to the `README` in [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

resnet = tf.contrib.slim.nets.resnet_v1

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
pred = resnet.resnet_v1_50(x)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(pred))
```

But got such an error:`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.slim' has no attribute 'nets'`. I have already installed the latest version of `tensorflow-0.12.0`.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

import like this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import resnet_v1

slim = tf.contrib.slim
```